# IncIompatible pointer types sending 'CWPWEntity *' to parameter of type 'CWPWModule * _Nonnull'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I made some changes to swift class so that it would be used in objective-c by using @objc syntax.

By doing so the function in the Project-swift.h file us showing like this

```
- (void)addFromServiceWithSource:(CWPWModule * _Nonnull)source;
```

In the function, _Nonnull is added by system itself

and while calling the function in `objective-c` class it gives a warning

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'CWPWEntity *' to parameter of type 'CWPWModule * _Nonnull'

and when I pass the value app crashes.

How should I do this

```
[self.entityGroupData addFromServiceWithSource:entityType];
```

Comment: Your object 'entityType' has type CWPWEntity instead of CWPWModule. And when you try to send it, it crashes because of incompatible type.

Comment: Ohh my bad... Thanks a lot @Eridana now i get it.